# How to use Animated.diffClamp in react native

Tags: android, animation, react-native

Any code example of how to implement Animated.diffClamp?

I'm trying to create a header scroll animation like the one featured in the google play app. I already hide the header when you start scrolling down, but the problem is that I want to show the header again as soon as you start scrolling up, it shows only when you reach the top of the view.

```
class Services extends Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    scrollY : new Animated.Value(0),
  }
}

renderScrollViewContent(){
  return (
    <View style={styles.scrollViewContent}>
    </View>
  )
}

render() {
  const headerHeight = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 60],
    outputRange: [0, -60],
    extrapolate: 'clamp'
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this.state.scrollY}}}]
        )}
      >
        {this.renderScrollViewContent()}
      </ScrollView>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.header, {top: headerHeight}]}>
        <View style={styles.bar}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Title</Text>
        </View>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

We added this exactly for this use case. Here's the doc page https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated#diffclamp

I also recommend using it with a translate transform (better perf and can be used with native driver). Here's your example render using it:

```
const headerTranslate = Animated.diffClamp(this.state.scrollY, 0, 60)
  .interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, -1],
  });
 
return (
 <View style={styles.container}>
   <ScrollView style={styles.container}
     scrollEventThrottle={16}
     onScroll={Animated.event(
       [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this.state.scrollY}}}]
     )}
   >
     {this.renderScrollViewContent()}
   </ScrollView>
   <Animated.View style={[styles.header, {transform: [{translateY: headerTranslate}]}]}>
     <View style={styles.bar}>
       <Text style={styles.title}>Title</Text>
     </View>
   </Animated.View>
 </View>
);
```

How it works is we pass the scroll position to diffClamp so it is clamped between 0 and 60, after we use interpolate to make the value negative (we want it to translate up).

Comment: I'm trying to implement diffClamp with Animated.event using native driver.

But I seem to have very little control over the result of the animated value.
I would like to make the same header scroll as the iOS Facebook app, but I'm running into several problems.
I can't seem to prevent the header from hiding when at the top of the view or oversrolls the view. Also if the user stops scrolling while the navbar is in the middle of the slide animation it should animate to fully hidden/visible. I dont see how I can implement any of these when I can't read the current scroll value from the event.

Comment: Implementing that is more complicated but it is possible using an animated value listener.  You can take your scroll Animated.Value and add a listener to it and implement the same logic as diffClamp does to get the current value and animate accordingly when scrolling stops. I implemented it but sadly I can't find the repo anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I didn't think the value from the listener would be performant enough to use as value for the animation, but it seems that it performs the same as the animated value from the event. Currently I pass the value from the listener to a function that performs the needed calculations incl. the clamping and then using setValue on a new animated.value which is used for the animation. Is that more or less the way you implemented it, or should I do it differently?

Comment: I actually implemented it a few days ago, I'll clean it up and post it here.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I made a repo with an example https://github.com/janicduplessis/collapsible-navbar

Comment: Nice, my implementation is similar, but I think I can make some improvements based on your repo. Thanks for putting it up :)

Comment: Any idea how you can prevent the bounce back of a header when using diffClamp?

For example everything is great when your scroll up and down. But what if you pull to refresh. The bounciness of the listview makes the header hide.

Comment: @JensDebergh were you able to find a solution to this issue of the bounciness?

Comment: @tnaught We were able to solve our specific problem by adding `bounces: false` on the listview. This may or may not be a solution to your problem but it was for us at the time.

Comment: I have spent over an hour looking for a way to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 23):

Here is an example with a header appearing from the top, only after the user has scrolled to a minimum Y position, and solving the overscroll/bouncing problem by clamping.

```
const minScroll = 100;

const clampedScrollY = scrollY.interpolate({
  inputRange: [minScroll, minScroll + 1],
  outputRange: [0, 1],
  extrapolateLeft: 'clamp',
});

const minusScrollY = Animated.multiply(clampedScrollY, -1);

const translateY = Animated.diffClamp(
  minusScrollY,
  -AnimatedHeaderHeight,
  0,
);

const opacity = translateY.interpolate({
  inputRange: [-AnimatedHeaderHeight, 0],
  outputRange: [0.4, 1],
  extrapolate: 'clamp',
});
```

More details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51638296/82609

Answer (score 0):

Starting from `V0.65` of `react-native` you can use `stickyHeaderHiddenOnScroll` props.

Here is the documentation to do so : https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.65/scrollview#stickyheaderhiddenonscroll

As a reminder, `Expo SDK43` support only `react-native: 0.64.3`.