# React Native - Bounce effect in iOS messing with Animated diffclamp

Tags: ios, animation, react-native

EDIT: I hate googling for answers and finding some question that never got solved from 10 years ago so I am answering my own question for those that might want to know. In my case, I simply disabled the `bounces` prop for the scrollview. Since FlatList extends React's ScrollView, setting `bounces` to `false` in the animated FlatList component that I created stopped it from bouncing and solved my problem. Have a nice day.

hope you're having a great day. I am trying to animate my header dynamically but for some reason whenever I scroll beyond the beginning or the end of the scrollview, the bounce effect messes with the Animation.(as shown in the gif below)

[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL7Wo.gif)

[Same GIF but higher resolution](https://giphy.com/gifs/animated-react-native-stackoverflow-2WGDEbiCWRJ0RejHOb)

As you can see, when I scroll to the top and enable the bounce animation, the header thinks that i am scrolling down as the bounce returns the first element in the list back to the top. How do I fix this? I saw on the web somewhere that adding an interpolator to the animated value would help, though I don't really understand.
Below is my code. Thank You

```
const AnimatedFlatList = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(FlatList)
const tempArray = [
  // ...my data
]
export default class TempScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      animatedHeaderValue: new Animated.Value(0),
    }
  }
  render() {
    const animatedHeaderHeight = Animated.diffClamp(this.state.animatedHeaderValue, 0, 60).interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 70],
      outputRange: [70, 0],
    })
    return (
      <View>
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            borderBottomColor: '#DEDEDE',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            padding: 15,
            width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
            height: animatedHeaderHeight,
          }}
        />
        <AnimatedFlatList
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
          onScroll={Animated.event([
            {
              nativeEvent: {
                contentOffset: {
                  y: this.state.animatedHeaderValue,
                },
              },
            },
          ])}
          data={tempArray}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 30 }}>{item.name}</Text>
              <Text> {item.year} </Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to solve the "bounce" problem only, the problem is that iOS gives to diffClamp negative scrollY values. You need to filter these and ensure scrollY remains >= 0 to avoid diffClamp being affected by overscroll.

```
const clampedScrollY = scrollY.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 1],
  outputRange: [0, 1],
  extrapolateLeft: 'clamp',
});
```

Another nice trick is to use a "cliff" technique, so that the header only disappear after a minimum scrollY position.

Here is code from my app:

```
const minScroll = 100;

const clampedScrollY = scrollY.interpolate({
  inputRange: [minScroll, minScroll + 1],
  outputRange: [0, 1],
  extrapolateLeft: 'clamp',
});

const minusScrollY = Animated.multiply(clampedScrollY, -1);

const translateY = Animated.diffClamp(
  minusScrollY,
  -AnimatedHeaderHeight,
  0,
);

const opacity = translateY.interpolate({
  inputRange: [-AnimatedHeaderHeight, 0],
  outputRange: [0.4, 1],
  extrapolate: 'clamp',
});
```

`clampedScrollY` will be:

- 0 when scrollY=0
- 0 when scrollY=50
- 0 when scrollY=100
- 30 when scrollY=130
- 170 when scrollY=270

You get the idea. So `diffClamp` will only be > 0 if scrollY > 100, and increment 1 by 1 after that threshold.

Comment: Also, here is a nice article for diffClamp animations: https://medium.com/appandflow/react-native-collapsible-navbar-e51a049b560a

Comment: Your solution is working for the bouncing effect at the top of the flatlist, but not at the very bottom, if you scroll far down, the bounce effect will go up and but back the opacity to 1. Do we have a more recent solution regarding this ?

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: @SebastienLorber do you have any suggestion on how to solve the same problem when we reach the bottom of the list? I have an infinitely loaded list, and header reappears every time I reach the bottom to load a new page.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem like two hour ago...

You can set `Scrollview` property `bounces=false` but if you want a `RefreshControl` for refreshing the `ScrollView` content (like in my case), the bounce property has to stay active.

I fixed this following this cool article: https://medium.com/appandflow/react-native-collapsible-navbar-e51a049b560a.

I'm not an expert of the Animated library, so I post my code:

```
constructor(props) {

    const scrollAnim = new Animated.Value(0);
    const offsetAnim = new Animated.Value(0);

    this.state = {
        scrollAnim,
        offsetAnim,
        AnimatedViewHeight: 1,
        clampedScroll: Animated.diffClamp(
            Animated.add(
                scrollAnim.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 1],
                    outputRange: [0, 1],
                    extrapolateLeft: 'clamp',
                }),
                offsetAnim
            ),0, 1
        )
    }
}

render() {

    const minScroll = this.state.AnimatedViewHeight;

    const navbarTranslate = this.state.clampedScroll.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, minScroll],
        outputRange: [0, -minScroll],
        extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });

    return (
        <View style={{
            flex: 1
        }}>

      <Animated.View
        onLayout={(event) => {
          var { height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
          this.setState({
              AnimatedViewHeight: height,
              clampedScroll: Animated.diffClamp(
                    Animated.add(
                          this.state.scrollAnim.interpolate({
                                inputRange: [0, 1],
                                outputRange: [0, 1],
                                extrapolateLeft: 'clamp',
                          }),
                          this.state.offsetAnim
                    ), 0, height)
          })
        }}
        style={[{ transform: [{ translateY: navbarTranslate }] }]}>

       <View><Text>THIS IS YOUR HEADER</Text></View>

       </Animated.View>

       <AnimatedFlatList
           // iOS offset for RefreshControl
           contentInset={{
               top: this.state.AnimatedViewHeight,
           }}
           contentOffset={{
               y: -this.state.AnimatedViewHeight,
           }}
           scrollEventThrottle={1}
           onScroll={
               Animated.event(
                        [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollAnim } } }],
                        { useNativeDriver: true },
               )}
               data={this.state.data}
               keyExtractor={(item, idx) => idx}
               ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
               renderItem={this.renderItem}
               onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
               refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl
                        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                        onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
                        // Android offset for RefreshControl
                        progressViewOffset={this.state.AnimatedViewHeight}
                    />
                }
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.5} />
        </View>

    )
}
```

`this.state.AnimatedViewHeight` is the height of the header, retrieved by calling `onLayout` function. Inside of this function I also set a new clampedScroll because I have a new height (In my case, the header doesn't have a fixed size).
After that, in `render()`, define a variable (`navbarTranslate`) for control the headerSize based on the scroll position of your Animated Scrollview.

Answer (score 4):

This is an implementation that works for bounces in both directions (at the start and at the end of the list).

```
    const minScroll = 100;
    const headerHeight = 65;
    const activeRange = 200;
    const yOffset = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

    const diffClamp = Animated.diffClamp(
        yOffset,
        -minScroll,
        activeRange + minScroll
    );
    const translateY = diffClamp.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, activeRange],
        outputRange: [0, -headerHeight],
        extrapolate: "clamp",
    });
```

The yOffset is passed to the onScroll prop of the ScrollView or Flatlist, e.g.,

```
onScroll={Animated.event(
            [
                {
                    nativeEvent: {
                        contentOffset: {
                            y: yOffset,
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
            { useNativeDriver: false }
        )}
scrollEventThrottle={10}
bounces={true}
```

It works as follows:

1. yOffset is the scrolled distance within the list and can take any value depending on the length of the list.
2. diffClamp maps the yOffset to a value between -minScroll and activeRange + minScroll. When yOffset is outside of this range, diffclamp essentially shifts this range to the difference outside the range so that it is always active when you change the scroll direction.
3. translateY is the value with which you want the header to move. The interpolation of translateY only accepts inputs in the range: 0 to activeRange, and thus does not respond to unless the scrolled distance is larger than minScroll (in both directions). The output equals -headerHeight to move the header up, and this output is clamped to keep the header hidden as the scrolling continues.

Note that by changing the activeRange, you can change the speed at which the header moves.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51638296/3639398

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Animated,
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions,
  RefreshControl,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import randomColor from 'randomcolor';

const HEADER_HEIGHT = 44 + Constants.statusBarHeight;
const BOX_SIZE = Dimensions.get('window').width / 2 - 12;

const wait = (timeout: number) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
  });
};
function App() {
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = React.useState(false);

  const scrollAnim = new Animated.Value(0);
  const minScroll = 100;

  const clampedScrollY = scrollAnim.interpolate({
    inputRange: [minScroll, minScroll + 1],
    outputRange: [0, 1],
    extrapolateLeft: 'clamp',
  });

  const minusScrollY = Animated.multiply(clampedScrollY, -1);

  const translateY = Animated.diffClamp(minusScrollY, -HEADER_HEIGHT, 0);

  const onRefresh = React.useCallback(() => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    wait(2000).then(() => {
      setRefreshing(false);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={styles.gallery}
        scrollEventThrottle={1}
        bounces={true}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={{
          zIndex: 0,
          height: '100%',
          elevation: -1,
        }}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollAnim } } }],
          { useNativeDriver: true }
        )}
        overScrollMode="never"
        contentInset={{ top: HEADER_HEIGHT }}
        contentOffset={{ y: -HEADER_HEIGHT }}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
        }>
        {Array.from({ length: 20 }, (_, i) => i).map((uri) => (
          <View style={[styles.box, { backgroundColor: 'grey' }]} />
        ))}
      </Animated.ScrollView>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.header, { transform: [{ translateY }] }]}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Header</Text>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  gallery: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    padding: 4,
  },
  box: {
    height: BOX_SIZE,
    width: BOX_SIZE,
    margin: 4,
  },
  header: {
    flex: 1,
    height: HEADER_HEIGHT,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    backgroundColor: randomColor(),
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

export default App;
```

checkout on Expo https://snack.expo.io/@raksa/auto-hiding-header