# Can we not position header using absolute positioning in react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am trying to hide header when scrolling the ScrollView top and showing it again when scrolling down. While searching the internet I came across some solutions using absolute positioning with animations. For e.g. as people suggested in this link https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/480.

The link I shared uses position absolute and updates the `top` using the interpolation. I am trying to do the same and cannot update it, instead I am getting the warning saying `position absolute is not supported on headerStyle`

How to change the header so that it hides when I am scrolling the ScrollView in a Screen using react-navigation.

**Shared Navigation Options**

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: MainListing,
    Details: DetailsScreen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: { backgroundColor: customTheme.COLORS.PRIMARY },
      headerTitle: (obj) => {
        return (
          <Image source={Logo} style={{ resizeMode: 'contain', width: 100, height: 100 }} />
        )
      },
      cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' },
    },
  }
)
```

**Static Navigation Options On Screen**

```
class MainListing extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <ScreenContainer>
        <ScrollView>
          //some other components so that the view scrolls
        </ScrollView>
      </ScreenContainer>
    );
  }
}

const ThemedElement = withGalio(MainListing);
ThemedElement.navigationOptions = ({ navigation, navigationOptions }) => {
  const { params } = navigation.state;
  return {
    headerStyle: {   
      position:'absolute',   
      ...navigationOptions.headerStyle
    }
  };
};
export default ThemedElement;
```

Comment: Not sure, but did you tried `static diffClamp(anim, min, max)` ? Docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#diffclamp

Comment: Where are you using ThemedElement?

Comment: @satya164 ThemedElement is the MainListing component in the stackNavigator, the Home screen.

Comment: @FábioBCSouza Yes I want to use this, but how do we do this? The values should be assigned to some property of header, if I am not wrong?

Comment: did u try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41901966/how-to-use-animated-diffclamp-in-react-native

Comment: You can use `headerTransparent` instead. It'll position the header absolutely. It'll also remove the background but you can add it back with `headerBackground: () => <HeaderBackground />`

Comment: @satya164 I tried it, it still gives the same warning and style doesn't apply. :(

Comment: How does headerTransparent give you the same warning if you don't even use position: absolute