# React Native pushing component in and out of screen dynamically

Tags: react-native

[image: Browser]

As shown in the attached gif, the navigation bar at the bottom and the URL bar at the top are pushed in and out(not just show/hide at once) of view as user scrolls. How can I achieve this 'hiding' effect in React Native? The key point is that the hiding speed of the component should correspond to the scrolling speed.

I have tried giving negative values to the top and bottom, like so:

```
style={{bottom:dynamicallyChangingScrolledValue()}}
```

although it does push the view out of the screen, space where the component used to remain in the blank, occupied.

Are they using animations here? or changing some offset value dynamically by incrementing a small amount?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Animated.diffClamp in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41901966/how-to-use-animated-diffclamp-in-react-native)

Comment: @karlmarxlopez Thanks! had a look and it helped. Have a good day