# React Native Tab view always has the height equal to height of the highest tab

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, expo

### Introduction

I have a FlatList that renders a Tab View in its footer. This Tab View let the user switch between one FlatList or an other. So, these last are sibling FlatLists.

### Problem

The first FlatList "A" has a greater height than the second one "B". When I choose the second list, its height is the same as the "A" FlatList's one.

I have reproduced the problem in a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@victoriomolina/my-tabview) where you can see a similar code. I recognize that the code is a little long but too simple, just focus only on the parent FlatList (in the App component) and the two FlatLists that are rendered in each tab (at the end of the code)

### QUESTION

Any ideas how to solve this issue? I don't know if the problem is in the styles or if I have to do something else to make this work (all flatlists have to have their own height, not the greater).

Thank you, I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: why do you need a tab inside FlatList footer?

Comment: Because when I scroll, the header and TabBar should also go up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### UPDATE 2022

```
  const renderScene = ({ route }) => {
    //
    //  Note: We are hidding tabs in order to avoid the
    // "FlexBox Equal Height Columns" typical problem
    //
    switch (route.key) {
      case "bitcoin":
        return (
          <View style={index !== 0 && styles.hidden}>
            <Bitcoin />
          </View>
        );

      case "ethereum":
        return (
          <View style={index !== 1 && styles.hidden}>
            <Etherum />
          </View>
        );

      case "rose":
        return (
          <View style={index !== 2 && styles.hidden}>
            <Rose />
          </View>
        );

      default:
        return null;
    }
  };


...

<TabView
  renderTabBar={renderTabBar}
  navigationState={{ index, routes }}
  renderScene={renderScene}
  onIndexChange={handleOnIndexChange}
  initialLayout={{ width: layout.width }}
  removeClippedSubviews={false}
  swipeEnabled
  swipeVelocityImpact={0.2}
  gestureHandlerProps={{
    activeOffsetX: [-30, 30], // To solve swipe problems on Android
  }}
  style={globalStyles.flexContainer}
/>
```

Styles:

```
hidden: { display: "none" }
```

---

I have updated the snack with the solution!

As in the snack I implemented my own TabView, I have decided to implement the same solution with the library "react-native-tab-view", as it is the best tab for react native for now.

Think that some people having this [issue](https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view/issues/290) will be able to solve it.

Basically, what we need to do is to dinamically calculate the height of each tab scene and pass it to the style of the TabView using the onLayout prop.

Just like this:

```
 const renderScene = ({ route }) => {
    switch (route.key) {
      case "inifiniteScrollFlatList":
        return (
          <FirstRoute />
        );
      case "rawDataFlatList":
        return (
          <View
            onLayout={(event) => setTab1Height(event.nativeEvent.layout.height + TAB_HEIGHT)}
          >
            <SecondRoute />
          </View>
        );
      case "otherRawDataFlatList":
        return (
          <View
            onLayout={(event) => setTab2Height(event.nativeEvent.layout.height + TAB_HEIGHT)}
          >
            <ThirdRoute />
          </View>
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  <TabView
      style={ index !== 0 && {
        height: index === 1 ? tab1Height : tab2Height,
      }}
      renderTabBar={renderTabBar}
      navigationState={{ index, routes }}
      renderScene={renderScene}
      onIndexChange={setIndex}
      initialLayout={initialLayout}
      removeClippedSubviews={false} // Pd: Don't enable this on iOS where this is buggy and views don't re-appear.
      swipeEnabled={true}
  />
```

Pd: You shouldn't do this with a tab that uses an infinite scroll with pagination. Instead, you will have to set the height to null to allow the parent FlatList to automatically get its height.

Comment: the 2022 update is great and still relavent. Thanks for that solution - it's the only one I have gotten to work!

Comment: thank you -- the tab hiding solution is still the best solution -- I wish it was just baked in :)--gestures is largely not used UI any more so it makes less sense to keep this just to support that. 
Also styling height doesn't work for tab views in web, which makes the updated solution worse. Strangely other properties do work like backgroundColor. No idea why and the docs don't address it.

Answer (score 1):

So, I haven't gone through the entire code, nor did I find a solution to your height problem.

But, what you can do is check out React navigation 5 -> [createMaterialTopTabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/).

It lets you create tabs with separate flatlist for each tab. It will solve the height problem because what is being rendered are separate flatlists as per the active tab. And it will also, make your code much cleaner.

You won't have to use a Flatlist with header and footer components to render the tabs with nested Flatlists.

And if you want to hide the tabs on scroll, that is possible by passing props to the tab navigator that toggle visibility on scroll of the Flatlist using the onScroll event that is called when a Flatlist is scrolled. The same can be done for the visibility of the header as well. And with the proper animations it would look as if the header and the tabs were pushed up on scroll like it does right now.

Comment: Actually I am needing to render the tab and the header inside a parent flatlist. Just because the parent flatlist will fetch data for Tab2 and Tab3 when refreshing, and Tab1 has its own database listener. That is why implemented it like this. Will I be able to fix the height problem if I nest the Tab from React Navigation 5 instead?

Comment: Basically I need to make it similar to the Instagram or Twitter profile screens.

Comment: In the snack I implemented my own tab but in my real code I am using "react-native-tab-view", used by React Navigation 5, and still having the same issue. I have read this issue on https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view/issues/290 and the library implementator said: "there's nothing special, you measure the layout of components with onLayout and set height with style."

Comment: You can fix the height problem, but you cannot move those tabs to the center. They sit on the top and below the Stack navigator's header. But, I might be wrong because I haven't tried moving those tabs to the center of the screen. What you can probably do is make the Stack navigator's header exactly like the header you want. So, that will move the tabs to where you want them to be (center of the screen) and have flatlists in seperate components that are called when the tabs are active. That might just work actually. But, its gonna be a lot of work. It should solve the height problem for sure.

Comment: Yep, even I've been looking to do something like Insta and Twitter profile screens. But, the solution I gave above was what I was going to implement. I found another question quite similar to this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54693590/tabs-with-flatlists-inside-scrollview-like-instagram-or-twitter-profile-pages You might have also seen it, perhaps. Apparently, everyone's looking for an answer to this problem. In case, I do find a solution for this, I'll share it here.

Comment: But if you do that like this, will the stack header move up when you scroll down any of the tab FlatLists?

Comment: Yep, stack header has a prop that toggles it's visibility. You can probably use that, Im not really sure though.  But, the trick is in getting the animations right to give that smooth user experience on scroll and making the stack header and the topTabs slide up and become invisible along with the scroll. It is just too much work to be honest. But, I found this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41901966/how-to-use-animated-diffclamp-in-react-native perhaps it might be helpful to get the animations right.

Comment: I have solved the issue. As I wasn't wanting to cause a re-render on my childs I had to dinamically calculate the height and set it using the onLayout prop. You can use this without the stack to have a refresh control on the parent flatlist (in my use case, this parent flatlist fetch data for two tabs, so I needed to show a refresh control).

Comment: I will post the answer here when I implemented it in my real code.

Comment: Awesome, glad you found a solution. And yes, please do post the answer. While, I don't have enough rep to upvote it, I can definitely send you good wishes and thoughts. Have a great day. :D

Answer (score 1):

I ended up removing the tabs content from the tab control altogether. It's hacky but worked for me...

```
 render() {
const {index} = this.state;
return (
  <ScrollView>
    <TabView
      renderPager={this._renderPager}
      renderScene={() => null}
      onIndexChange={index => this.setState({index})}
      initialLayout={{height: 0, width: Dimensions.get('window').width}}
    />
    {index === 0 && <Tab1Content />}
    {index === 1 && <Tab2Content />}
  </ScrollView>
);
```

Source:-  https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view/issues/290#issuecomment-447941998

Comment: I was using this solution some time ago, but I noticed a little performance issue due to the multiple remounts... The best approach (at least the one I am using now) is to use `display: "none"` ( CHECK THE UPDATE ;) )