# How can I prevent scrolling if the data is empty in particular cases?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two Top Tabs. Each tab has a component that receives data from an API,

I have wrapped these tabs in scroll view by adding animations,
When you press the second tab, the component shows up on the screen with a swipe animation.

But I have an issue. If I'm in Tab 1 and the tab's component has a long list of data; after scrolling to the end, if I press Tab 2 the scroll indicator shows up in Tab 2 as well, "at the end of view"!

So, can I make the Tabs have separate scrolls?

I've made a live example [here](https://snack.expo.io/@anastely/b58a1f)

> Try to scroll down in Tab "opened". Then go to Tab "closed" you will
> see the issue

here's the code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Animated,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const SPACING = 20;
const SLIDE_WIDTH = width - SPACING * 2;

export default function App() {
  const [openedOrders, setOpenedOrders] = React.useState([]);
  const [closedOrders, setClosedOrders] = React.useState([]);

  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(0);
  const [xTabOne, setXTabOne] = React.useState(0);
  const [xTabTwo, setXTabTwo] = React.useState(0);

  const [translateX] = React.useState(new Animated.Value(0));
  const [translateXTabOne] = React.useState(new Animated.Value(0));
  const [translateXTabTwo] = React.useState(new Animated.Value(width));
  const [translateY, setTranslateY] = React.useState(-1000);

  const handleSlide = React.useCallback(
    (type) => {
      Animated.spring(translateX, {
        toValue: type,
        duration: 100,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
      if (active === 0) {
        Animated.parallel([
          Animated.spring(translateXTabOne, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: 100,
            useNativeDriver: true,
          }).start(),
          Animated.spring(translateXTabTwo, {
            toValue: width,
            duration: 100,
            useNativeDriver: true,
          }).start(),
        ]);
      } else {
        Animated.parallel([
          Animated.spring(translateXTabOne, {
            toValue: width,
            duration: 100,
            useNativeDriver: true,
          }).start(),
          Animated.spring(translateXTabTwo, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: 100,
            useNativeDriver: true,
          }).start(),
        ]);
      }
    },
    [active, translateXTabOne, translateX, translateXTabTwo]
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    active === 0 ? handleSlide(xTabTwo) : handleSlide(xTabOne);
  }, [active, handleSlide, xTabTwo, xTabOne]);

  return (
    <>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          marginTop: 20,
          marginBottom: 20,
          position: 'relative',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          borderRadius: 15,
          height: 61,
          backgroundColor: '#ccc',
        }}>
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            width: '50%',
            height: '100%',
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            borderRadius: 15,
            transform: [
              {
                translateX,
              },
            ],
          }}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            height: 61,
          }}
          onLayout={(event) => setXTabOne(event.nativeEvent.layout.x)}
          onPress={() => {
            setActive(1);
          }}>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 18,
              color: active === 0 ? '#262626' : '#fff',
            }}>
            opened
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            height: 61,
          }}
          onLayout={(event) => setXTabTwo(event.nativeEvent.layout.x)}
          onPress={() => {
            setActive(0);
          }}>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 18,
              color: active === 1 ? '#262626' : '#fff',
            }}>
            closed
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <ScrollView
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
        // contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}
      >
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            transform: [
              {
                translateX: translateXTabOne,
              },
            ],
          }}
          onLayout={(event) => setTranslateY(event.nativeEvent.layout.height)}>
          <FlatList
            data={
              []
              // Array(900).fill(0)
            }
            contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}}
            ListEmptyComponent={() => {
              return (
                <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#999' }}>
                  <Text>No data here...</Text>
                </View>
              );
            }}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
              return <Text key={index}>hey: {index}</Text>;
            }}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.toString()}
          />
        </Animated.View>
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            transform: [
              {
                translateX: translateXTabTwo,
              },
              {
                translateY: -translateY,
              },
            ],
          }}>
          <FlatList
            data={Array(900).fill(0)}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
              return <Text key={index}>hey: {index}</Text>;
            }}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.toString()}
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </ScrollView>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully work out what you want, but it looks like you want two FlatLists side-by-side.

The first step is getting them side-by-side. We'll make a container view, measure its width, have a second container view inside that we transform, then in the second container view, we'll put both FlatLists.

```
const Example = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(0)
  const [width, setWidth] = React.useState(0)
  const [translateX] = React.useState(() => new Animated.Value(0))

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(translateX, {
      toValue: active * width,
      duration: 300,
      useNativeDriver: true
    }).start()
  }, [active, width, translateX])

  return (
    <View
      style={{flex: 1}}
      onLayout={e => setWidth(e.nativeEvent.layout.width)}
    >
      <Animated.View style={{flexDirection: 'row', transform: [{translateX}]}}>
        <FlatList style={{width: width}} {…flatlist1Props} />
        <FlatList style={{width: width}} {…flatlist2Props} />
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Now when you change active tab, it'll automatically slide to the right list.

You don't need the extra ScrollView if you only wanted to use your tabs to change between lists.

Comment: Hey @Jacob Thank you for answering, can you please make a snack that achieves your point? cuz it does not work as expected

Comment: FlatList Component look at this [screenshot](https://imgur.com/q7FfI40)

Comment: Try adding `position: “absolute”, top: 0, left: 0, height: “100%”` to the second container view

Answer (score -1):

There's a library called [React Navigation v5](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started)

It provides an easy solution for creating [Top tabs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator) with animation.

Instead of creating the tabs all by yourself and adding animation, I'd suggest you use that library to create top tabs.

It provides a very clean solution, where you can create two separate components for each of your tabs and add them to the respective tabs.

The content and the logic of the components will not interfere with each other.

This way you will not have to nest FlatList inside the ScrollView as well.

Do think about using the library. It provides some great solutions for navigation in React Native Apps.

This will solve most of the problems you are presently facing with the current implementation.

Here are a few Youtube Videos that demonstrate how to use React Navigation v5:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQVCkqvU1uE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KVJhOYOn1g

p.s: The first Video is a whole lot better, content and explanation wise.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for sharing this info, I'm already using RN v5 in my app but the whole issue with it, I don't know how can I make `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` as a standalone component to use it in my screen like this 
`<> 
   <Header />
   <Body />
   <TopTabs /> // createMaterialTopTabNavigator
</>`

Comment: Uh, I just export a constant `TopTabs` in navigation file then import it in any screen and it's work well :"D But I guess should I implement my custom Tabs cuz I don't have any option to add style for active Tab like background or borders as u see in the snack

Comment: You can actually change the background and borders. In tabBarOptions add  activeTintColor: 'white', inactiveTintColor: black, (To change the color of the text). And add indicatorStyle: { backgroundColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'black' }.  This should work. I don't use backgroundColor in my tabs usually. But,  borderBottomColor in indicatorStyles does work that I'm certain of.

Comment: Also, if you want to make your screen like <Header /> <Body /> <TopTabs /> Instagram or Twitter profile screen style. Check out this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63606479/react-native-tab-view-always-has-the-height-equal-to-height-of-the-highest-tab/63611264?noredirect=1#comment112488233_63611264 This user has implemented it. But, I haven't really tried it out yet, so I'm not sure.